# Is it a good idea using a mascot illustration for personal branding?

Tags: designers, branding, portfolio

It’s the first time I make a website and portfolio for myself.
I work mostly doing UX/UI design, but I’m into illustration.

I’d like to make a branding that is personal to me. I draw animals and my idea was having a small illustration in the website besides my name and title and not a logo.

I’m having some second thoughts because I don’t know if it’s irrelevant for my position to make my website portfolio this way. I’m not into getting into a super serious company like finance or anything, but I don’t want to seem unprofessional.

If you could give me some tips for achieving a personal portfolio I’d be super grateful too!

Thanks :)

Comment: Sure, why not use a mascot? It's an avatar which is common for digital things

Comment: Searching something like "modern brand mascot" will show you lots of companies that do this sort of thing. You could very reasonably do it for your personal brand. I think most people don't have something like that for their personal brand because they don't want to put in the time, not because it's innately bad.

Answer (score 1):

Whether that's a good or bad idea is kind of subjective. Its probably good, if you think this would help you land more jobs.

One thing's for sure, clients looking at portfolios are mostly interested in the actual work delivered, not the mascot.

Comment: What if the potential client is looking for someone to design a brand mascot? :D